# PTIJ - עדים in a pandemic

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

In light of the current pandemic, with many people operating through zoom, would witnesses that gave עדות (testimony) remotely be regarded as עדים זוממין?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Not sure, but a lot of women of valor have been Zillow-surfing:  זָמְמָה שָׂדֶה, וַתִּקָּחֵהוּ;

Comment: @DoubleAA what's wrong? It's a pun on Zoom

Comment: @msh210 As is, you could remove the disclaimer and it reads as a sincere question. If you put in a shuruk mark there, I don't even see it as much of a question; it's a joke sentence with a question mark at the end. We require that question be "the kind that invite answers"

Comment: Thanks @msh210 - feel free to edit if you think it can be made PTIJ-worthy

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Absolutely, but there are various halachot that relate to Eidim Zoomemin stated throughout Shas that must be followed:

The Eidim must be the host(s) of the Zoom meeting - אין העדים נעשים זוממין עד שיזומו את עצמן. ([source](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Makkot.1.4?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he))

Both Eidim must be remote - אין העדים נעשין זוממין עד שיזומו שניהן ([source](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.28a.6?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he))

The Eidim are not killed until everyone is muted (until the [din](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/din) is complete) - אין העדים זוממין נהרגין, עד שיגמר הדין ([source](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Makkot.1.6?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he))

Comment: Sources please. :)

Comment: +1 - great answer!!

Comment: +1 - excellent wordplay.

Comment: @robev sources have been added.